# Printing a list using a pointer to that list

Tags: c++, list

I have a function that prints a list. However, I'm passing a pointer to that list, and the following code for printing lists does not work; that is, the code that would print a list if it were not being pointed to.

```
print(std::string svar, std::list<person> *persons){
    for (std::list<person>::iterator it = persons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to change it to account for `persons` being a pointer.

Comment: You need to dereference your pointer: `persons->begin()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways to solve it.

1. Change the argument to the function from a pointer to a reference.

   ```
   void print(std::string svar, std::list<person> const& persons){
       for (std::list<person>::const_iterator it = persons.begin(); it != persons.end(); it++) {
           std::cout << *it << " ";
      }
   }
   ```
2. Change the way you use the pointer.

   ```
   void print(std::string svar, std::list<person>* persons){
       for (std::list<person>::iterator it = persons->begin(); it != persons->end(); it++) {
           std::cout << *it << " ";
      }
   }
   ```

I would advise using the first option.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `persons` is a pointer to a list, not the list itself. Use the `->` operator to dereference it:

```
void print (std::string, std::list<person> *persons)
{
    for (std::list<person>::iterator it = persons->begin(); it != persons->end(); it++) 
    {
      std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

Or better yet, take it as a reference and use a range based for loop (assuming C++11):

```
void print (const std::list<person>& persons)
{
  for (auto&& person : persons)
  {
    std::cout << person << " ";
  }
}
```

You might consider naming pointer variables differently, e.g: `person* pPerson`.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to pass an object without copying it is to use a reference, not a pointer:

```
print(std::string const & svar, std::list<person> const & persons);
```

You can access members of the `list` via the reference exactly as you would with the `list` object itself, so your code should work if you fix the const-correctness:

```
for (std::list<person>::const_iterator it = persons.begin(); ...
                        ^^^^^^
```

which, since C++11, can be done more conveniently:

```
for (auto it = persons.begin(); ...
```

or

```
for (person const & p : persons) {
    std::cout << p << " ";
}
```

If you really want to muck about with a pointer for some reason, then access the `list` members using `->` rather than `.`

```
for (auto it = persons->begin(); it != persons->end(); ++it)
                      ^^
```

You should also make sure that it's not null first, since such a function invites people to pass null pointers.